# How do I order my WP Query by meta value and only get certain values from a different meta?

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP Car Manager to manage the vehicle inventory on my site. I want to use Slider Revolution to display a "Hot Deals" slider. I want the slides to be only vehicles that have the "Featured" option checked(wpcm_featured = 1). Then I want to  order the slides by the price(wpcm_price) of the vehicle.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function slider_hot_deals($query, $slider_id) {

    // only apply the special filter for slider with "x" ID
    if($slider_id == 4) {

        // order posts by vehicle price
        $query['meta_key'] = 'wpcm_price';
        $query['orderby'] = 'wpcm_price';
        $query['order'] = 'ASC';
        $query['meta_type'] = 'NUMERIC';

    }

    return $query;

}
add_filter('revslider_get_posts', 'slider_hot_deals', 10, 2);
```

At the moment, that only gets all vehicles and orders them by price. How can I modify this so that it supports multiple meta values which are then used in the orderby and where clauses?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple meta querys in one query, here's an example of what I was just coding yesterday:

```
$query_args = array (
    'post_count' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'kanga_kurs',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'start_date' => array(
            'key' => '_startdatum',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'start_time' => array(
            'key' => '_startzeit',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'kursort' => array(
            'key' => '_kursort',
            'value' => $this->get_id(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'start_date' => 'ASC',
        'start_time' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
```

For more information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query